# How to configure the frequency of the cluster health ping in elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to configure the frequency of the cluster health ping in elasticsearch. We see the following TRACE logs and it seems to be too frequent and we want to increase the time, how should we configure that.

```
2021-05-24T13:21:44,827 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-8] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [21a8cd67] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:21:44,829 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [21a8cd67] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:21:51,615 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-9] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [2febc45] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:21:51,617 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [2febc45] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:22:14,855 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-10] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [565b2636] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:22:14,872 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [565b2636] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:22:21,631 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [89414b7] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:22:21,633 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [89414b7] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:22:44,886 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-4] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [4a5f5e5a] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:22:44,889 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [4a5f5e5a] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:22:51,660 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-3] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [232d2aab] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:22:51,662 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [232d2aab] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:23:14,908 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-2] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [1e5880a] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:23:14,924 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [1e5880a] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:23:21,692 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-5] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [1d302aa5] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:23:21,694 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [1d302aa5] Received raw response: 200 OK
2021-05-24T13:23:44,929 TRACE [http-nio-5555-exec-6] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [68fc1254] Sending request GET /_cluster/health/ with parameters: 
2021-05-24T13:23:44,931 TRACE [I/O dispatcher 1] o.s.d.e.c.ClientLogger: [68fc1254] Received raw response: 200 OK
```

Comment: you probably have some monitoring set up for your application that calls the _/actuator/health_ endpoint of your application. Configure that monitoring to do less calls.

Comment: Is it coming from 'co.elastic.apm', name: 'apm-agent-attach',